# shadowOffset is not working in react native android

Tags: android, react-native, shadow

shadowOffset is not working for me in android react native.

here is my code,

```
<View style={styles.viewimage}>
   <Image
       style={styles.picture}
       source={require('../../../assets/img/vijy.jpg')}
   />
</View>
```

**Style:**

```
viewimage:{
  backgroundColor:'yellow',
  shadowOffset:
   { 
    width: 10,
    height: 10,  
  },
  shadowColor: 'black',
  shadowOpacity: 1.0,
 },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
viewimage: {
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  shadowColor:'black',
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 3
  },
  shadowRadius: 5,
  shadowOpacity: 1.0,
  elevation: 5
},
```

This will work. `elevation:5` for Android remaining properties for iOS.